# Can't Switch to Azure Function Classic Experience

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

Recently i have discovered that ability to change to Classic Experience of Azure Function portal is not there right now. I have used some functions that has been created in old Power Shell module and since that i had to create it with Experimental Language.

Is there any others experiencing same issue as mine. Please help me on this.

[image: Missing switch to classic experience link]

[image: what its supposed to be earlier]

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to create a new function or view old ones?  I'm in a similar position, and found an older work around for calling PnP from site script via .NET.  MS docs still reference the method you are talking about, though.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning#create-the-azure-function

https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2019/01/Site-Designs-PnP-Part1.html

[image]

Found some additional documentation here!

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning.md

Last date edited was 07/04/2020.

Answer (score -1):

The new portal experience of Azure functions became general this year.

[image]

You can check out this YouTube video published my Microsoft about the **"How to"** of this experience: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bdT_9uOqkg

If you don't want this view, you can **Switch to classic experience**.

Comment: It was there about week ago.. suddenly there is no place switch back to classic view.. I don't know whether they have deprecated the classic view of the Azure Function.

Comment: Yes, I checked that. Since the new experience is same as old one, are you not able to see your function app? What is the issue?

Comment: New experience doesn't have place to turn on Experimental languages. Thats the problem..

Comment: Let me circle back on this.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I also need the Experimental Languages.

Comment: Which experimental language are you targetting?

Comment: Does using custom handlers help? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers

Comment: I got a response from the PG that this is removed from the portal. If you need a language that’s not natively supported you can still use custom handlers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Checking, if this helps or not.